Is there a writing norm in Occitan in which [y] is written as <ü> and [u] as <u>?
Maybe also [y] as <ù> or [u] as <ò>?

Yes, there is such norm although limited in both time and space.
Representing /y/ as "ü" is a German usage and unsurprisingly, it is only found in Occitan texts written in Germany, more precisely in Württemberg by exiled Huguenots Waldesians and their descent who escaped Occitan Piedmont valleys by the end of the 17th century.
Here is a sample text from Ernst Hirsch, Das Patoisgedicht der Anna Gille aus Serres, Zeitschrift für französische Sprache und Literatur, 77, 170-180, 1967.

Another reference, very detailed: Paola Malavaso, Regresso e scomparsa di un dialetto, La penetrazione del tedesco nel provenzale alpino parlato nelle colonie valdesi del Württemberg
,  page 38, 1997.
The main Occitan writing norms are the classical one where /y/ is "u" and /u/ is "o" and the Mistralian one where /y/ is also "u" and /u/ is "ou" (like in French).

I'd recommend using "quotes" or  for written letters, and /slashes/ only for phonemes, to make it clear which is which—"/u/ is /o/" could go either way.

@Draconis That was a typo, fixed. Thanks.
